# How can I get the name of a Swift function as a string?

Tags: swift, string, function, introspection

If I have functions in a Swift class like:

```
class MyClass: NSObject {
    class func drawingOne(frame: CGRect) {}
    class func drawingTwo(frame: CGRect) {}
}
```

And elsewhere I have a variable that is set to one of the functions, eg:

```
let drawingFunction = MyClass.drawingOne
```

How can I get the name of the drawing function as a string, eg:

```
let text = name(of: drawingFunction)
```

to give:

```
"MyClass.drawingOne"
```

Note that this is not the same as using:

```
let myName = #function
```

inside each function. I have a variable that points to a function and I want to get the name of that function from the variable.

Comment: No. That "possible duplicate" allows you to modify a function to extract its name using #function. But here I have a variable that points to one of many functions and I need to ask that variable for the name of the function.

Comment: I am fairly sure that this is not possible. Note that your variable could also be set to a closure (which has no name): `let drawingFunction = { (frame: CGRect) in }`